# Easy virtualization method

Tags: virtualization, sandbox

We are developing an online judge system to test students' computational geometry problems solutions. At this moment wee need a testing environment: we have to limit time and memory usage (to accept only optimal solutions), and since we run untrusted code, we have to forbid some system calls (like fork), disable networking, etc. What would be the easiest (open source) virtualization solution for this task? As far as I understand, I will have to use a patched kernel (like OpenVZ), or it is possible to find a simple tool, which will accept restrictions and untrusted program as its arguments and run it?
P.S. If it is important — we run c++ code, however, we would like to use a universal solution.

Answer (score 1):

If the problems involve only stdin/stdout, e.g. read some input then calculate output, you may have a look at [seccomp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seccomp) It's really simple.

Also in near future a [second mode of seccomp](http://lkml.org/lkml/2012/2/24/490) may be come into the kernel which will give you more flexible.